# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.GenericList<chartInfo> to 'chartInfo'

Tags: android, xamarin

I am creating a listview where it can parse data when click to next page. I am using the Get string Extra method. However, there are error where says Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.GenericList to 'chartInfo'

```
 string chartId = Intent.GetStringExtra("chartId") ?? string.Empty;
                if (chartId != string.Empty)
                {

                    chartInfo chartinfo = general.getchartInfo(chartId);
```

Comment: What is that variable "generic"?? post your full code

Comment: The `getchartInfo(chartId);` returns a `List` of `chartInfo` while you have declaredthe variable `chartinfo` as just a `chartInfo` object. As you may notice, you should probably do something about your naming, because it's confusing ;) Anyhow, change the last line in your code to `var chartinfo = general.getchartInfo(chartId);` and it should work.